Angular 19, WriteableSignal for array which dynamically changed
I have a writeable signal in a service:
private errorEntries: WritableSignal<ErrorEntry[]> = signal<ErrorEntry[]>([])

I have a getter in the service:
  getErrorEntries(): WritableSignal<ErrorEntry[]> {
    return this.errorEntries;
  }

and another methode addError create new instance with spred operator.
  public addError(error: any): void {
    const timestamp = new Date().toISOString();
    const message = error.message || error.toString();
    const stack = error.stack || 'No stack trace available';
    const route = this.router.url;

    const errorEntry: ErrorEntry = { timestamp, message, stack, route };
    this.errorEntries.update((entries) => [...entries, errorEntry]);
  }

I have an effect in ANOTHER component which displayed on the header.
  showExclamationMark = false;

  constructor(private globalErrorHandlerService: GlobalErrorHandlerService) {
    effect(() => {
      const errors = this.globalErrorHandlerService.getErrorEntries()();
      this.showExclamationMark = errors.length > 0;
    });
  }

The effect works fine. But the errors.length always empty, why?
I don't see what I missed.
I noticed during debug in the service one of the errorEntries property
has a value:
  SYMBOL(Signal): 
    value: Array(1)

contains a value.
I interested in what I missed, what I did wrong?

please replicate the issue in this stackblitz and share back, issue is not reproducible and problem lies somewhere else in your code.

Would suggest the below improvements.
We can define the private variable with a _.
private _errorEntries: WritableSignal<ErrorEntry[]> = signal<ErrorEntry[]>(
  []
);

We can make the getter an asReadonly signal, since the method only seems to modify the signal.
get errorEntries(): Signal<ErrorEntry[]> {
  return this._errorEntries.asReadonly();
}

Then for your scenario, you do not really need an effect (Because they are mean't for side effects/DOM updates) but your scenario is a derived state from the original state. So the better solution is to use computed to calculate it.
showExclamationMark = computed(() =>
  this.globalErrorHandlerService.errorEntries().length > 0 ? '!' : ''
);

Full Code:
import {
  Component,
  Injectable,
  inject,
  WritableSignal,
  signal,
  Signal,
  effect,
  computed,
} from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';

export interface ErrorEntry {
  timestamp: string;
  message: string;
  stack: string;
  route: string;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class GlobalErrorHandlerService {
  private _errorEntries: WritableSignal<ErrorEntry[]> = signal<ErrorEntry[]>(
    []
  );

  get errorEntries(): Signal<ErrorEntry[]> {
    return this._errorEntries.asReadonly();
  }

  public addError(error: any): void {
    const timestamp = new Date().toISOString();
    const message = error.message || error.toString();
    const stack = error.stack || 'No stack trace available';
    const route = '';

    const errorEntry: ErrorEntry = { timestamp, message, stack, route };
    this._errorEntries.update((entries) => [...entries, errorEntry]);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    {{showExclamationMark()}}
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'asedf';
  showExclamationMark = computed(() =>
    this.globalErrorHandlerService.errorEntries().length > 0 ? '!' : ''
  );

  constructor(private globalErrorHandlerService: GlobalErrorHandlerService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.globalErrorHandlerService.addError(new Error('adsfasdf'));
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo
